# How to update all datetime records to UTC time in a SQL Server database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL Server database with ~1000 tables. Most of the tables have `datetime` columns with different name. Currently the value stored there is with offset because the code inserted it with the current date from the server.

**The goal is to have all datetime records in UTC time.**

Now I want to do two things:

1. Using some of these 3 functions (`SYSDATETIME, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET, SYSUTCDATETIME`) I can get the offset. Next step is to find all datetime records and update them. Can you help me with this?
2. Some of the datetime columns have default value `GETTIME`. I want to update that with `SYSUTCDATETIME`. Any idea how?

PS: I do not want to change the columns' type to `datetimeoffset` because the type is not supported in MSSQL Server 2005.

**EDIT**: Because there are so many comments about `datetime` and the topic of the question was shifted in different direction I suggest you not to think about `datetime` column type but for `int`. The problem is still the same. Updating many tables and changing the default value of columns.

Best Regards
mynkow

Comment: How data is stored with an offset? as Varchar?

Comment: You can't do it that way. The difference between local and utc is not constant (daylight savings and more).

Comment: @usr: why not, if updated time is between April-November(summer time) I will add +1.

Comment: @ClearLogic: The answer is in the first line of the question: Most of the tables have datetime. The offeset is included in the datetime, not a separate value => http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx

Comment: how on earth you can store timezone offset in Datetime. even MSDN says NO in the link you sent  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826837/how-to-store-timezone-in-sql-server-2005

Comment: How do you get the offset in TSQ?  This fails for me select DATEPART(TZoffset, GETDATE())

Comment: to get server’s current time zone offset   SELECT DATENAME (TZoffset, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET())

Comment: @ClearLogic thanks   I do email threading were I need to match a subject with a date and think this will fix a long standing problem.  I did not know about type datetimeoffset.

Comment: @ClearLogic: Let's say that the server (application+DB) is in time zone +1 and current UTC is 1am. The datetime value in the database will be 2am. This is what I meant with 'offset included'. In my prev comment I said that offset is not a separate value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dynamic SQL to update all user databases on your server.
The first query outputs to the Results tab.
The second query outputs to the Messages tab.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
GO

---------------------------------------------
-- #1 Dynamic SQL to update DATETIME values with UTC offset
DECLARE @t TABLE(TABLE_CATALOG VARCHAR(128), TABLE_SCHEMA VARCHAR(128), TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(128), COLUMN_NAME VARCHAR(128));

INSERT @t
EXEC sp_msforeachdb 'select db = "?"
, s.name
, t.name
, c.name
FROM [?].sys.tables t
JOIN [?].sys.columns c ON c.object_id = t.object_id
JOIN [?].sys.types y ON y.user_type_id = c.user_type_id
JOIN [?].sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
WHERE t.[type] = ''U''
AND y.name = ''DATETIME''
AND "?" NOT IN (''master'', ''tempdb'', ''model'', ''msdb'')';

DECLARE @Offset INT;
SET @Offset = - DATEPART(TZOFFSET, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET());

SELECT [SQL] = 'UPDATE ['+ C.TABLE_CATALOG +'].[' + C.TABLE_SCHEMA + '].[' + C.TABLE_NAME + '] SET [' + C.COLUMN_NAME + '] = DATEADD(MINUTE,' + CAST(@Offset AS VARCHAR(5)) + ',[' + C.COLUMN_NAME + ']);' 
FROM @t C;
GO

---------------------------------------------
-- #2 Dynamic SQL to change DATETIME column defaults to SYSUTCDATETIME
DECLARE @t TABLE([SQL] VARCHAR(MAX));
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX);

INSERT @t   
EXEC sp_msforeachdb 'SELECT [SQL] = ''---------------------------------------------'' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
    + ''-- [?].[''+s.name+''].[''+t.name+''].['' + c.name + '']'' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
    + ''ALTER TABLE [?].[''+s.name+''].[''+t.name+'']'' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
    + ''DROP CONSTRAINT [''+d.name + '']'' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
    + ''GO'' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
    + ''ALTER TABLE [?].[''+s.name+''].[''+t.name+''] ADD CONSTRAINT'' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
    + ''[''+d.name+''] DEFAULT (SYSUTCDATETIME()) FOR [''+c.name + '']'' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
    + ''GO'' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
    FROM [?].sys.default_constraints d
    JOIN [?].sys.columns c  ON  c.default_object_id = d.object_id
    JOIN [?].sys.types y ON y.user_type_id = c.user_type_id
    JOIN [?].sys.tables t ON t.object_id = d.parent_object_id AND t.[type] = ''U''
    JOIN [?].sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
    WHERE y.name = ''datetime''
    AND "?" NOT IN (''master'', ''tempdb'', ''model'', ''msdb'')';

DECLARE C CURSOR FOR 
SELECT * FROM @t

OPEN C
FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @SQL;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
    PRINT @SQL;
    FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @SQL;
END

CLOSE C;
DEALLOCATE C;
GO
```

Comment: Thank you John. God bless you! sp_msforeachdb is WOW

Comment: How can I have the SQL statements executed as well rather than just being printed out?